# A php code able to exec all SQL code

Tags: php, sql

I'm making an intranet.
Only admin have access to the page i want to build now :
I have a page with a textarea. When they click on the send button, it comming to a PHP page to send a req like `"UPDATE  ... "` or `"SELECT ...".`
He can write the SQL request he want. It's supposed to works.

I want it to work : If it's an update i need to return he if it's ok, if its a select i need to return a table.

But i need it to be able to exec complex request like :

```
 SELECT numfou, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM PROPOSER P 
WHERE P.numfou = F.numfou) AS NB_PROD 
FROM FOURNISSEUR F;
(net exemple).<br/>
```

Do you know a PHP code to exec any SQL req?

Comment: Yes i know, install **PHPMyAdmin** for them :) It's `a PHP code`

Comment: I don't whant them to have acces to phpmyadmin ,i'm using it yet. My job is to build them an "SQL" page (the same in phpmyadmin) :D But thanks, you understand me.

Comment: If it was that easy to be done in one page everybody would be doing it. There a ton of issues with building such a thing. Why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: "re-invent the wheel" that's a good question, two answers : to learn, and because they told me so :P (clients don't want to touch phpmyadmin)

Comment: make a text area, post the query, execute it, and or/loop over the results, display the response. Can't be that hard if no safety considerations are in place

Comment: If you want to learn, try it yourself first then and come back with some code/problem explanation if you've got any issues. You can probably find good inspiration in phpmyadmin. if client doesn't want to use existing tools, I hope he's ready to pay for you re-inventing the wheel...

Comment: Bartdude, your comment don't help. Look at the code at the bottom, tried something. But it don't works with AVG(), COUNT(), MAX(), MIN() and SUM() have you an idea to update ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this code i make (If you think it can be update say it :D) :

```
<?php
function requette($req){
    $premierMot = explode(" ", $req)[0];
    switch(strtoupper($premierMot)){
        case "SELECT":
            return select($req);
            break;
        case "UPDATE":
        case "DELETE":
        case "INSERT":
            return updateDeleteInsert($req);
            break;
    }
}

function select($req){
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=spb', 'root', '');

    // ON DETERMINE SI LE CLIENT RECHERCHE DANS CHAMPS EN PARTICULIER OU TOUT
    $explosion = preg_split('/[;, \n]+/', $req);
    $veuxTout = false;
    for($cpt=0;$cpt<count($explosion);$cpt++){
        if(strtoupper($explosion[$cpt]) == "*"){
            $veuxTout = true;
            break;
        }   
    }

    // SI IL NE VEUX PAS TOUT ON PREVOI UN TABLEAU DE DEMANDE
    $demande = array();
    for($cpt=1;$cpt<count($explosion);$cpt++){
        if(strtoupper($explosion[$cpt]) == "FROM"){
            break;
        }
        else{
            array_push($demande,$explosion[$cpt]);
        }
    }

    // ON CHERCHE LE NOM DE LA TABLE
    $table = "";
    for($cpt=0;$cpt<count($explosion);$cpt++){
        if(strtoupper($explosion[$cpt]) == "FROM"){
            $table = $explosion[$cpt+1];
            break;
        }   
    }

    // ON CHERCHE LES TITRES DE LA TABLE
    $sql =  "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='$table';";
    $res = $bdd->query($sql);
    $titres = array();
    while($resultat = $res->fetch()){
        array_push($titres,$resultat['COLUMN_NAME']);
    }

    $res = $bdd->query($req);
    $table = "<table>";
    while($resultat = $res->fetch()){
        $table .= "<tr>";
        if($veuxTout == true){
            for($cpt=0;$cpt<count($titres);$cpt++){
                $table .= "<td>".$resultat[$titres[$cpt]]."</td>";
            }
        }
        else{
            $ok = false;
            for($cpt1=0;$cpt1<count($titres);$cpt1++){
                for($cpt2=0;$cpt2<count($demande);$cpt2++){
                    if(strtoupper($titres[$cpt1]) == strtoupper($demande[$cpt2])){
                        $table .= "<td>".$resultat[$titres[$cpt1]]."</td>";
                        $ok = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $table .= "</tr>";
    }
    $table .= "</table>";
    return $table;
}

function updateDeleteInsert($req){
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=spb', 'root', '');
    try {
        $req = $bdd->prepare($req);
        $req->execute();
        return "oui";
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        return "non";
    }
}

$req = htmlentities($_POST['req']);
echo requette($req);
?>
```